# scrollViewWillBeginDragging not responding on a second UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, xcode

I have a probably nub question but i just can't get around this.
I have a UIScrollview on the top of the screen, below it there is a UITableView.
both are on my InterfaceBuilder, not done programmatically 
and declared on my .h as:

```
@interface RootViewController : UIViewController <UIScrollViewDelegate, IconDownloaderDelegate>
{
IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollview;
}
```

etc.

Inside the UIScrollView i have a long tabbar also in IB mi code is as follows for this:

```
[scrollview setScrollEnabled:YES];
[scrollview setContentSize:CGSizeMake(1100, 29)];
```

Everithing works perfectly the tabbar works and moves etc.

the problem is that when implementing scrollViewWillBeginDragging
it only registers the scrolling on my UITableView and not on the scrollview.

```
- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{

    NSLog(@"done");

}
```

What am i doing wrong??

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you set the delegate for the scroll view ?

Comment: noup as a metter of fact i haven't how do i set the delegate for this specific scrollview?

Comment: scrollview.delegate = self; if you are implementing the delegate in the class you are setting the above.

Comment: can you explain who is the delegate to your scroll view?

Comment: damn!! how could i miss that!! thanks a bunch could you post it as an aswer so i can give you the credit? THANKS!

Comment: Ok i have added it as an answer :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set the delegate to the class where you implement the delegate methods.

```
scrollview.delegate = self;
```

Answer (score 0):

add `[scrollview SetDelegate:self];` in the place you add scrollview